# DFA intersection algorithm for special cases

Tags: automata-theory, time-complexity, dfa

I'm interested in efficient algorithms for DFA intersection for special cases. Namely, when the DFAs to intersect obey a certain structure and/or operates on limited alphabet. Is there any source where I can find algorithms such cases?

In order to not make the question too broad, the following structure is of particular interest: all the DFAs to intersect operate in the binary alphabet (0|1), they can also use don't care symbols. Moreover, all the states have only one transition except for at most K special states, which have only two transitions (and these transitions are always 0 or 1, but no don't care). K is an integer, less than 10 for practical purposes. Also, they have a single accepting state. Additionally, it is known that the intersection is ALWAYS a DFA in form of "strip", i.e., no branches as in the following image:

[image]

**EDIT:** Perhaps the description of the constraint on the input DFAs is not very clear. I will try to improve it in this paragraph. You have as input **T** DFAs. Each of these DFAs operates only on the binary alphabet. Each of them has at most **N** states. For each DFA, each of its states is one of the following:

1) the accepting state (it is only one and there's no transition from it to any other state)

2) a state with two transitions (0 and 1) to the same target state (the majority of the states is of this kind)

3) a state with two transitions (0 and 1) to different target states (at most **K** of this kind)

It is guaranteed that there's only one accepting state and that there are at most **K** states of type (3) in each input DFA. It is also guaranteed that the intersection DFA of all the input DFAs is a "strip" (as described above), of size less than **N**.

**EDIT2:** Some additional constraints, as requested by D.W. in the comments:

- The input DFAs are DAGs.
- The input DFAs are "levelled", following the D.W. definition in the comments. Namely, you can assign different integers to every state in such a way that every transitions goes from an integer **u** to an integer **v**, such that **u + 1 = v**.
- The number of accepting states for each input DFA, doesn't exceed **K**.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you model "don't care"? It seems to make the automata nondeterministic, in a way.

Comment: @Shaull Why should it make the automaton non deterministic. That can happen only if there is another transition from the same state, which is explicitly excluded.

Comment: What is `a DFA in form of "strip", i.e., no branches`? Do yu have any specific reason to believe one can do better than the standard algorithm in your case?

Comment: @babou I don't have a special reason to believe one can do better. My question is about it's possible to do better. A "strip" is a DFA like s0 -> s1 -> ... -> sN.

Comment: Hi, are you asking for an algorithm to compute the intersection or are you asking for an algorithm that decides if the intersection is non-empty?

Comment: Hi. Computing the actual intersection would be great, since it would simplify many things, but deciding the emptiness would be useful as well.

Comment: Could you provide an example? "Strip" is not clear and I wonder if "don't care" is a transition with both 0,1.

Comment: @MichaelBlondin I added an image of the "strip". And yes, "don't care" is a transition with both 0,1 to the same target state. Sorry for the misleading explanation and thanks for your time.

Comment: Are there any more guarantees about your input DFAs?  Are they guaranteed to be DAGs, for instance?  Are they guaranteed to be "levelled" (each state can be labelled with an integer, its level, and every transition goes from a state of some level $\ell$ to a state at the next level $\ell+1$)?  If they're levelled, the problem looks trivial.  Is there an upper bound on the number of states in each input DFA? (e.g., $O(N+K)$?  something better than $2^K N$?)  Any guarantees about the number of accept states in the input DFAs?

Comment: @D.W. The input DFAs are DAGs, "levelled" and the number of accepting states is at most K, for each DFA.

Comment: @D.W. well, that would contradict the answer of MichaelBlondin below, wouldn't it? But anyway, I will edit it and I would love to discuss your approach. Thanks a lot.

Comment: just ran across a new paper on [intersection graphs](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_graph), could some of this theory be relevant? could you plz expand on your application mentioned in your comment in [chat]? & invite others to continue further discussion there.

Comment: @kaktusito: I edited my answer to match your new question.

Comment: It is amazing that you discuss at length features that are true of any
DFA on a 2-symbols alphabet, while not stating a major hypothesis such
as the lack of cycles, which implies finiteness of the language. I do not think you deserve the upvotes you received.

Comment: Maybe my initial description wasn't clear enough, but for me it was obvious that the DFA's were DAGs. And about the upvotes ...... :) do you really have time to think about such things when discussing such beautiful topics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, there are some cases of the DFA non emptiness insersection problem that are inside P. My [master's thesis](http://www-etud.iro.umontreal.ca/~blondimi/doc/fr/msc.pdf) is devoted to this question, but unfortunately it is in French. However, most of the results have appeared [here](http://www-etud.iro.umontreal.ca/~blondimi/doc/publications/BlondinKrebsMcKenzie2014.pdf) in $[2]$.

When the alphabet is unary, then the problem is L-complete when each DFA has at most two final states, and NP-complete otherwise. Most of the other cases are restriction on the transition monoids of the automata. For example, for abelian group transition monoids, the problem is in $\text{NC}^3$ when each DFA has at most one final state, and NP-complete otherwise; for elementary 2-group transition monoids, the problem is $\oplus$L-complete when each DFA has at most two final states, and NP-complete otherwise.

---

Let me now address your more precise question, which can only be found in $[1]$. Suppose you are given DFAs working over $\{0,1\}$ and shaped as trees, i.e there exists a state $u$ (initial state) such that for each state $v$ there exists a unique path from $u$ to $v$. Then, deciding the intersection non emptiness is:

1. L-complete for one final state in each DFA,
2. NL-complete for two final states in each DFA, and
3. NP-complete for three or more final states in each DFA.

The hardness results still hold even if you "fork" respectively 0, 1 or 2 times (this is your $K$). Now if your DFAs are directed acyclic graphs instead of trees, then the problem is NP-complete even with one final state in each DFA and $K=2$; the reduction is quite straightforward and is from Monotone 1-in-3 3-SAT.

Therefore, **no**, I don't think there is an efficient algorithm for your problem.

Now, if the number of automata is fixed, you might want to discuss with [Michael Wehar](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/14207/michael-wehar) who has recently published $[3]$.

---

EDIT: Since OP edited his question, let me clarify my answer with his new requirements. Consider the NP-complete problem *Monotone 1-in-3 3-SAT* where you are given a formula in 3-CNF without negation, and where you have to determine whether there is an assignment that makes *exactly* one variable true in each clause. You can reduce this problem to the non emptiness intersection problem as follows. For example, for the clause $x_2 \lor x_3 \lor x_5$, you build the following automaton:

$\hskip2in$[image: reduction gadget]

Note that the automata are trees (and hence DAGs), are levelled, and have three final states. Actually, the three final states coud be merged into a single one, if one is satisfied with DAGs. Moreover, only two states have two (distinct) outgoing transitions.

1. [Michael Blondin. Complexité raffinée du problème d'intersection d'automates, M.Sc. thesis, Université de Montréal, 2012.](https://papyrus.bib.umontreal.ca/xmlui/handle/1866/8440?locale-attribute=en)
2. [Michael Blondin, Andreas Krebs et Pierre McKenzie. The Complexity of Intersecting Finite Automata Having Few Final States, Computational Complexity (CC), 2014.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00037-014-0089-9)
3. [Michael Wehar. Hardness Results for Intersection Non-Emptiness. ICALP, 2014.](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-662-43951-7_30)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I accept your answer. The question originated from some practical tests where everything reduced after many steps into intersecting the solutions of many DFA with this particular characteristics. Nevertheless, we observed that although at the end we  would obtain a simple DFA, the process never finished because of the intermediate DFAs (while sequentially intersecting) were wildly growing into an exponential number of states. Thus the question, of how to obtain the answer without going through the intermediary "naive" steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot (and sorry for being unclear, I'm below novice in this area). Now there's something I don't get. You mention that "shaped as tree" means "unique path from the root to every other node". But, for example, in the image you posted in the edit, that wouldn't be a tree (unless you count the 0/1 transitions as a single label)?

Comment: You are right, but my understanding was that you allow "don't care" transitions. Isn't it the case?

Comment: It is; moreover, it seems like I use "don't care" and "0/1 transition" interchangeably. Is this technically correct?

Comment: Well, I am not aware of any widespread definition of an "automaton shaped as a tree", so it's only a matter of how you define it. If you consider a 0/1 transition as a single one, then this construction yields trees, otherwise not. In any case, it is still a DAG and levelled.

Comment: Well, in any case, the problem is rendered NP-Complete, isn't?

Comment: As far as I understand your requirements, yes indeed.

Comment: Hi Michael.  Thanks for the nice answer.  I hope all is well.  :)

Comment: Little remark: Any problem solvable in non-deterministic linear time using at most $k\log(n)$ bits of memory has a nice little reduction to intersection non-emptiness for k DFA's that look like DAG's.  This is a small hardness result for the case where you have a fixed number of DFA's that look like DAG's.

Comment: While I was driving home tonight I thought quite a bit more.  It turns out that fixing both the number of DFA's and the number of final states is the right idea.  If you give me k DFA's that are shaped like trees such that each DFA has at most n states and at most c final states, then you can solve intersection non-emptiness deterministically using at most $k\log(c)+\log(n)$ space.  In other words, if both k and c are fixed, then you can solve it quickly.  Feel free to contact me if you would like to discuss or if I made an error.  Have a great day!  :)

Comment: You are right, in this case the problem is L-complete.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!  I'm glad you both got me to start thinking about the intersection problem again.  :)

Comment: @MichaelWehar In case you fix both k and c, you mention you can solve the problem "quickly". But you don't mention the time complexity, only the space complexity. What exactly "quickly" means in that context?

Comment: I created a chat room for anyone interested: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20120/emptiness-of-intersection-and-related

Comment: Hi Kaktusito, if you can solve a problem in $m\log(n)$ space, then you can solve it in $n^m$ time.  For our problem, to be safe, we can solve it in something like $k^c + n^2$ time.  So if k and c are fixed and not too large, then we can solve it *quickly*.  Also, thanks for creating the room.

Comment: If you're interested in implementing it, I could go through all the details and explain the algorithm in the chat.  :)

Comment: @MichaelWehar Yes, indeed I'm interested, and also about the motivation of the problem itself. Let's continue in the chat. Thanks.

Comment: Correction: $c^k+n^2$.

Comment: More details were added in the chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20120/emptiness-of-intersection-and-related